# Pass `fields` parameter in Google Calendar API

Tags: python, google-api

I'm getting user events using [Events.get](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get#try-it) method. However whenever I try to provide the selected `fields` I want, it returns an error saying `Invalid field selection creator(displayName,email)`.  It doesn't matter what fields I list, i get a similar error.

What wrong am I doing?

This is my python code:-

```
request = calendar_service.events().list(calendarId=calendar_id,
                                         syncToken=sync_token,
                                         fields='creator(displayName,email)')
```

Comment: I notice the eventID missing. What is the default?
Secondly: did you only try subfields, or also non-indexed fields, like:
fields = 'location'
?

Answer (score 3):

These previous answers are no longer accurate. The fields parameter is now documented in depth here: https://developers.google.com/calendar/performance#partial-response. From that page:

## Fields parameter syntax summary

The format of the fields request parameter value is loosely based on XPath syntax. The supported syntax is summarized below, and additional examples are provided in the following section.

- Use a comma-separated list to select multiple fields.
- Use a/b to select a field b that is nested within field a; use a/b/c to select a field c nested within b.

  **Exception**: For API responses that use "data" wrappers, where the response is nested within a data object that looks like data: { ... }, do not include "data" in the fields specification. Including the data object with a fields specification like data/a/b causes an error. Instead, just use a fields specification like a/b.
- Use a sub-selector to request a set of specific sub-fields of arrays or objects by placing expressions in parentheses "( )".

  For example: fields=items(id,author/email) returns only the item ID and author's email for each element in the items array. You can also specify a single sub-field, where fields=items(id) is equivalent to fields=items/id.
- Use wildcards in field selections, if needed. For example: fields=items/pagemap/* selects all objects in a pagemap.

Answer (score 2):

The parameter `fields` is not documented in the [**"Optional query parameters"**](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get#parameters). That is only a convenience for the example form. You would need to do some post-processing after getting the event resource back.

Here is the `python` documentation for the [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/python/latest/calendar_v3.events.html#get).

Answer (score 1):

The `fields` query parameter is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/performance#partial-response).

An example query: `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/<calendarId>/events/<eventId>?fields=creator,attendees(email)`

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation the 'fields' parameter doesn't exists. The response on the request contains all the information as a dictionary object.

So if you call:

```
request = calendar_service.events().list(calendarId=calendar_id,
                                     syncToken=sync_token)
```

Request contains everything you need. You can get the displayname by:

```
request['creator']['displayName']
```